# OnClicklistener not working for runtime views

Tags: android, view, onclick, tablelayout, tablerow

I am displaying a table in my application which is created at runtime. I want to make all of its rows clickable. Here i used the code.

```
            tableRow.addView(payeeNameText);
            tableRow.addView(dueDateButton);
            tableRow.setTag(1);
            accountBillsTL.addView(tableRow);

            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(v == (View)tableRow.getTag(1)){
               System.out.println("Row Clicked");
            }
            }
```

but while clicked on the row nothing happens. no value print at LogCat. Please help. How can i make rows clickable with runtime views. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your table row clickable and attach an onClick listener

```
tableRow.setClickable(true)
tableRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(View view){
   System.out.println("Row Clicked with tag " + view.getTag()); 
 }
})
```

**Attention: view.getTag() does not have any argument! this returns just an object. You added an integer as a tag for this view** so you can do something like this

```
if (((int) tableRow.getTag()) == 1) {
 bla bla
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't added a listener for the "runtime view" you created.

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: i have added tableRow.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: you should really add some more code. cannot make anything out from what is available.

Comment: you can also try
if(v.getId() == (View)tableRow..findViewWithTag("1").getId()){
           System.out.println("Row Clicked");
        }